# How can i run an Zap active scan using authentication?

Tags: owasp, zap

I am running this owasp zap command(`v2.13`) from the git repository that's running an active scan on an private API URL:

```
./zap.sh -cmd -quickurl https://private-url-example.cloud -quickout /tmp/report.html -quickprogress
```

I can generate reports just fine but I would like to add some authentication to this command if possible. How can I do this?

Comment: if it allows you to pass in headers and you use an auth token type you can put in a header, add that and it'll then be an "authenticated" scan

Comment: The complete answer is too long for a StackOverflow answer :)
However we have documented it pretty thoroughly here: https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/authentication/